# Which storage management scheme for a single file?

Tags: c++, file, memory

I have an app that uses a file as its single backend storage. The app will regularly serialize the objects to the file. The objects are variable length and may grow and shrink during the lifetime of the app. It also needs to support modification of the values in the file directly bypassing the memory buffering of it. So for example objects of similar types (and others):

```
struct Data { std::vector<int> data; };
```

would be serialized and I will need to be able to:

- Retrieve the object on request
- Update the whole object on request
- Update individual values in that object stored in the file

To do that I need to implement a sort of "memory management" system with memory being the file. There are quite a few options but I don't seem to understand how some aspects of them work. I am considering:

- Buddy memory system
- Dynamic allocation

The problem I have is with reclamation of freed space. For example if an object grows beyond its allocated memory area I will move it to bigger one that can fit it. I need to keep track of the freed area for other requests.

More specifically, how do I detect and handle a case when two freed areas neigbour each other. All options I come up with have linear time complexity and suffer quite a lot from either memory waste or memory fragmentation.

What are the main options to do this and main points and pointers for implementing them?

Comment: It sounds like you are re-inventing SQLite. I would suggest looking at that; it does everything you want and has already been written and debugged.

Comment: @H.Guijt I have used SQLite extensively in the past but it cannot be used here. I need something really lightweight and able of serialization. With SQLite I would have to go throuh two layers (serializing to bytearray and then saving it to db as blob) which is very slow (tested it) and cumbersome to use. And it does not allow changing internals of values.